# What is the Cov(A,B)?

Tags: covariance

I am working on a problem: $Y = A+B+C$.
I know that $Cov(A,B+C)=0$,$Cov(B,C)=0$, $E(B)=0$ and $E(C)=0$.
Can I get the $Cov(A,B)=0$?
Now I can only get $Cov(A,B)=-Cov(A,C)$.
But it seems to be intuitive that both $Cov(A,B)$ and $Cov(A,C)$ should be zero?

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample, suppose $var(B) = var(C) > 0$, and $A = B - C$.

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
Cov(A, B+C) &= Cov(B-C, B+C) \\
&= E((B-C)(B+C)) \\
&= E(B^2 - C^2) \\
&= E(B^2) - E(C^2) \\
&= var(B) - var(C) \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}$$
but
$$\begin{aligned}
Cov(A,B) &= Cov(B-C, B) \\
&= E((B-C)B) \\
&= E(B^2 - BC) \\
&= E(B^2) - E(BC) \\
&= var(B) - Cov(B,C) \\
&= var(B) \\
&> 0
\end{aligned}$$